# Subfolder views expressjs 3x /nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

How can I use a subfolder for my 'views'? 
In the main 'app.js' I've set the root folder for the views like so:

```
 app.configure(function(){
       app.set('view engine', 'jade');
       app.set('views', __dirname + '/apps' );
       app.use(express.bodyParser());
       app.use(express.methodOverride());
       app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/apps' ));
       app.use(app.router);
 });
```

And my controller loos like this:

```
 module.exports = function(req, res, base) {
       res.render( 'hello/views/');
 };
```

The folder looks like this:

```
 ./apps/hello/views/index.js
```

But still it can't find it.  "ERROR: Failed to lookup view "hello/views"
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by setting the basis view to the root of the directory like so:

```
   app.set('views', __dirname);
```

And the added the folders from the root on in the controller like so:

```
   res.render( 'apps/hello/views/');
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I made a vastly better solution.
In the app configuration I just set the default view like so:"

```
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Later on I inlcude a  boot.js (based on the mvc example of expressjs ) in which I include the following:

```
 // allow specifying the view engine
 if (obj.engine) app.set('view engine', obj.engine);
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/../apps/' + name + '/views');
```

This will override the view folder to the one specified in the folder 'apps/xxx/views' and will even allow you to specify a new viewtype in the root of that folder like so:

```
 // filename = /apps/hello/index.js

 exports.engine = 'jade';

 // Render the indexpage
 exports.index = function(req, res, next){
      res.render('hello');
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that your self answer works, since you should be telling express to render a particular view, and hello/views is a folder. However I'm not familiar with the code pattern you're using for your controller (the `base` argument is what's throwing me off, since Express middleware uses `function(req,res,next)`.)

My routes look like this:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/apps' );
...
app.get('/hello', function(req,res){
  res.render('hello/views/index')
});
```

In this case `./apps/hello/views/index.jade` is a jade file, not a javascript file. If your templates are javascript, perhaps you should set `view engine` to something other than jade.

Answer (score 1):

You can set views as array of paths

```
app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, 'views/users/'), path.join(__dirname, 'views')])
```

You can check the resulting paths using app.get('views'); which should return an array.

```
[/server/views/users/, /server/views]
```

Express will search through the array for available paths. You can then render with just the file name like this

```
res.render( 'index');
res.render( 'profile');
```